# How do i see how all the generators get mapped during automorphism in GAP

Tags: group-theory, gap

I'm using [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org) for the first time.
I used `AllAutomorphism` command to see all automorphisms of SymmetricGroup of order $3$.

```
gap> AllAutomorphisms(SymmetricGroup(3));

     [ ^(), ^(2,3), ^(1,3), ^(1,3,2), ^(1,2,3), ^(1,2) ]
```

I want to understand what the output means?
I would also like to see how generators(or group elements) map during each automorphism map.

Comment: I've searched around but didn't find any way to obtain all set of generators of a group. There is a command GeneratorsOfGroup, but it only gives one set of generators.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to look for all generating sets of a group, because even for small groups there will be far too many. In fact $S_3$ has $50$ generating sets, (including those that contain the identity). Why would you want to do that?

Comment: And if you wonder where the number 50 comes from: `Number(Combinations(elms),x->Size(Group(x,()))=6);
`

Answer (score 8):

The notation `^perm` denotes an inner automorphism -- conjugation by the indicated permutation. The result tells you that $S_3$ has no outer automorphisms.
If you want to see the action on generators, you could use `AsGroupGeneralMappingByImages` to convert the representation:

```
gap> all:=AllAutomorphisms(SymmetricGroup(3));
[ ^(), ^(2,3), ^(1,3), ^(1,3,2), ^(1,2,3), ^(1,2) ]
gap> List(all,AsGroupGeneralMappingByImages);
[ [ (1,2,3), (1,2) ] -> [ (1,2,3), (1,2) ],
  [ (1,2,3), (1,2) ] -> [ (1,3,2), (1,3) ],
  [ (1,2,3), (1,2) ] -> [ (1,3,2), (2,3) ],
  [ (1,2,3), (1,2) ] -> [ (1,2,3), (1,3) ],
  [ (1,2,3), (1,2) ] -> [ (1,2,3), (2,3) ],
  [ (1,2,3), (1,2) ] -> [ (1,3,2), (1,2) ] ]
```

If you want to see what happens to group elements, you can apply the automorphisms with `Image'. For example

```
gap> elms:=Elements(SymmetricGroup(3));
[ (), (2,3), (1,2), (1,2,3), (1,3,2), (1,3) ]
gap> List(all,x->List(elms,y->Image(x,y)));
[ [ (), (2,3), (1,2), (1,2,3), (1,3,2), (1,3) ],
  [ (), (2,3), (1,3), (1,3,2), (1,2,3), (1,2) ],
  [ (), (1,2), (2,3), (1,3,2), (1,2,3), (1,3) ],
  [ (), (1,2), (1,3), (1,2,3), (1,3,2), (2,3) ],
  [ (), (1,3), (2,3), (1,2,3), (1,3,2), (1,2) ],
  [ (), (1,3), (1,2), (1,3,2), (1,2,3), (2,3) ] ]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm having a lot of fun using gap. It's like learning group theory all over again at a much deeper level.